# Can I have a different camera angle in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Am I able to set the camera angle to a certain block at a certain angle in singleplayer?  Specifically speaking, like this (starts at around 13:40):

Comment: As he stated in the video, he placed a camera at that position. It's part of a mod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of all the camera mods out there, the most popular is [Camera Studio](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/938825-146-camera-studio-v26-modloader-compatible-video-recorder/). This mod allows you to record timelapses, 'render' scenes by slowing down the world to get higher output FPS, as well as control camera position in a number of ways.

It is an advanced mod, so be prepared to spend a bit of time getting to grips with it to get the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

No this cannot be done without mods.  In this it looks like he's in multiplayer and someone else is filming.

Answer (score 1):

The common practice for doing this, is to have a friend record you via a MP server.

Answer (score 0):

Not without mods, no. You can get pretty close with flying creative in most cases though. Sadly, I'm not familiar with any utility mods that do this.

Comment: Your saying this can't be done in single player?

Comment: If you found/made a mod to do it, yes you could do it in single player. Might be easier to just do it in multiplayer though.